# Magit error: Wrong type argument: listp

Tags: magit, error

I recently updated magit and since then I haven't been able to create commits with it.

When I try to create a commit in the magit-status interface, I get the error:

```
command-execute: Wrong type argument: listp, #[257 "�C�����%��!Ǡ)��" [(#[128 "���!�
                                                                                   ł
                                                                                    ��#�" [#[385 "�����$��\")�" [#2 magit-commit-create #s(transient-prefix #s(transient-prefix eieio--unbound magit-commit eieio--unbound nil eieio--unbound eieio--unbound eieio--unbound nil nil ...) magit-commit 4 nil eieio--unbound nil eieio--unbound nil (nil) ...) make-closure #[0 "���\"����!���!������\"�����#�" [V0 V1 V2 eieio-oref unwind-suffix transient--debug unwind-command advice-remove eieio-oset nil] 4] apply] 7 "

(fn FN &rest ARGS)" nil] #[0 "�����$�" [#2 magit-commit-create #s(transient-prefix #s(transient-prefix eieio--unbound magit-commit eieio--unbound nil eieio--unbound eieio--unbound eieio--unbound nil nil ...) magit-commit 4 nil eieio--unbound nil eieio--unbound nil (nil) ...) make-closure #[257 "�C�����%��!Ǡ)��" [V0 V1 V2 t make-closure #[0 "���!���\"����!���!������\"�����#�" [V0 V1 V2 V3 eieio-oref unwind-suffix transient--debug unwind-interactive advice-remove eieio-oset ...] 4] advice-eval-interactive-spec nil] 8 "

(fn SPEC)"]] 5] apply called-interactively-p any funcall-interactively funcall] 5 cconv--interactive-helper]) magit-commit-create #s(transient-prefix #s(transient-prefix eieio--unbound magit-commit eieio--unbound nil eieio--unbound eieio--unbound eieio--unbound nil nil ...) magit-commit 4 nil eieio--unbound nil eieio--unbound nil (nil) ...) t make-closure #[0 "���!���\"����!���!������\"�����#�" [V0 V1 V2 V3 eieio-oref unwind-suffix transient--debug unwind-interactive advice-remove eieio-oset ...] 4] advice-eval-interactive-spec nil] 8 "
```

The backtrace after running `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET` is

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp #f(compiled-function (spec) #<bytecode -0x90bcd782274d766>))
  call-interactively(magit-commit-create nil nil)
  command-execute(magit-commit-create)
```

I tried:

- restart emacs
- uninstall and reinstall magit
- delete the `.emacs.d/elpa` and `.emacs.d/eln-cache` folders and run an empty emacs via `emacs -Q` and install only magit from Melpa via

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

and

```
M-x package-refresh-contents RET
```

and

```
M-x package-install RET magit RET
```

but the issue persists.

My magit version is:

```
Magit 20230905.1712 [>= 3.3.0.50-git], Transient 0.4.3, Git 2.41.0, Emacs 30.0.50, gnu/linux
```

My emacs version is:

```
GNU Emacs 30.0.50 (build 3, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.36, cairo version 1.17.6) of 2023-01-25
```

at this point I'm a bit out of ideas, since the error message I'm getting isn't really helpful, so any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I can commit in the same magit version, `Magit 20230905.1712 [>= 3.3.0.50-git], Transient 0.4.3, Git 2.35.3, Emacs 29.1, gnu/linux`.

Comment: Just to say, I am seeing the same issue (Emacs 30.0.50, Magit v3.3.0-751-gee0b557a)